# Anti-Squat Force Transmission

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering

I’m trying to understand how anti-squat works in motorcycles and how the geometry plays a major role.

[image]

I don’t understand, however, the reason why the force from the tires that is transmitted to the chassis of the bike via the swing arm is always along the axis/centre line of the swing arm and not parallel to the ground.

Comment: resolve that driving force into two components horizontal and vertical. Consider a wheelbarrow : is it easier to push it or pull it....

Comment: What is the significance of $y$?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have bearings at each end of the swing arm which can only take over radial or axial forces and no torques in z-direction. Therefore, you can only push or pull the swing arm and the force transmitted has to be in the same direction (in order to not create torque). The remaining forces have to be taken over by the dampers.

Comment: So, there’s no bending moment generated in the swing arm?

Comment: maybe in direction of y or x, but in this case you can consider the swing arm as a structure only transmitting tension and compression (and furthermore in your drawing there are no forces in the z direction). This assumption is often made if you have thin and long structures (rod like).